# Calling reject on the paypal.Promise returned in the payment method for PayPal

Tags: javascript, paypal, promise

```
payment() {
   return new paypal.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       reject(new Error('Invalid form!'));
   });
},
```

Anyone managed to call `reject` on the promise returned by PayPal payment method?

Everything seems to be working ok, the only problem is that in the browser console I get this error: `ppxo_unhandled_error`

Is this normal? Is there anyway that I can reject the payment request (so the PayPal window gets closed) but not have this error in the console?

So to reiterate I based my code on the following example: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/button.md#advanced-integration

This can also be reproduced here https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
with following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function() {
                var paymentPromise = new paypal.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    reject(new Error("Err!"));                   
                });

                paymentPromise.catch(function(err) {

                });

                return paymentPromise;
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Set up a url on your server to execute the payment
                var EXECUTE_URL = '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/payment/execute/';

                // Set up the data you need to pass to your server
                var data = {
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID: data.payerID
                };

                // Make a call to your server to execute the payment
                return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                    });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: rejecting a Promise === throwing an error

Comment: so, you want `payment` to always fail - interesting. What you don't do anywhere is handle the rejected promise - hence the warning

Comment: `This can also be reproduced here` - that doesn't seem to use paypal.promise at all

Comment: @JaromandaX it does if you use the code that I pasted bellow that sentence. I said `with following code:`

Comment: I don't want to always fail. This is just an example, the simples example to reproduce the error. I have some validations and if they fail I just want to close the paypal modal, and the only way to close it is if you reject the promise, but then I get the error in the console.

Comment: @Thomas I did also tried with a catch() for the paypal.Promise but even if it goes there, paypay library still logs that error. So looks like they don't care if I handle it (catch it) or not.

Comment: show us the code. Your snippet above doesn't `catch` anything. And I cannot reproduce that behaviour in their sandbox. If I `promise.catch()`, I don't get that message.

Comment: @Thomas I updated the code in the above question and added a catch to the promise. I then tested again and got exactly same error. What code have you used where it works without error? https://i.imgur.com/77wT4jj.jpg

Comment: As written you have two promise branches. You catch error from `paymentPromise` but then return `paymentPromise`, not the caught branch! Try `return new paypal.Promise(...).catch();`

Comment: Unless the returned promise is caught in the caller, then you will indeed get an "uncaught promise" warning.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same thing? Becasue `paymentPromise = new paypal.Promise` if I thest the code like you said I get different error "Uncaught Error: No value passed to payment"

Comment: No, it's not the same. That's why you are getting a different error message. "Uncaught Error: No value passed to payment" looks like an application level message, and probably the expected response to your catch if nothing is returned by the callback.

Comment: I tried like this `return (new paypal.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { reject(new Error("Err!")); })).catch(function(err) {});` and I got same error. Also I'm looking at the source code of the Promise library they use https://github.com/krakenjs/zalgo-promise/blob/master/src/promise.js#L107 and seems they always just call that `dispatchPossiblyUnhandledError` no matter what I do.

Comment: You missed my point about nothing being returned by the catch callback. Try returning a Number, eg `return (new paypal.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { reject(new Error("Err!")); })).catch(function(err) { return 1.99 });`

Comment: I don't understand where zalgo-promise is coming from. It's author seems to take great pride in having a feature which was roundly criticised in early jQuery promises - namely synchronous behaviour.

Comment: That's what PayPal is using. `new paypal.Promise` is actually an instance of zalgo-promise... https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/src/interface.js#L11 Also in the console error trace `at new ZalgoPromise (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:8871:25)`